# Error loading log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

Our application includes a Windows service that we can run as a console application for debugging & testing purposes.  It uses log4net to write log entries to the Windows Event Logs.

This morning, I installed our application on our development machine, then uninstalled it.  Since I uninstalled it, I've started getting the following error message whenever I start the service as a console application:

```
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Could not create Appender
        [EventLogAppender] of type [log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender]. 

      Reported error follows.
System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
    at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey
                 (String name, Boolean writable)
    at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.GetEventLogRegKey
                 (String machine, Boolean writable)
    at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration
      (String source, String machineName, Boolean readOnly, Boolean wantToCreate)
    at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.DeleteEventSource
        (String source, String machineName)
    at log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender.ActivateOptions()
    at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender
         (XmlElement appenderElement)

  The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
     MyComputer
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this?  Please note that event logging seems to be working, so I'm not clear what log4net is complaining about.

Comment: Have you tried to run you app as *administrator* ?

Comment: Whatever user account is running the service can't access whatever registry key Log4Net is trying to access.  Who the user is and what the key is I have no idea.  But it should be easy enough to find via Services and Process Monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need special (elevated) permissions to write to the application log (since you are using an `EventLogAppender` that writes to the Windows Event Logger).

Check the permissions for the current user.

Comment: The shortcut for running this application used to have "Run as administrator" checked off.  I don't know when or how, but that setting got unchecked somehow.  Turning it back on resolved the issue.

Comment: This is not quite accurate. You don't need elevated permission to *write* to Event Log. Only creation of  source requires that.

Answer (score 0):

Creation of an event source requires is essentially creation of a registry key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application`, that's why it requires elevated permissions. Contrary to the accepted answer, the application does not need elevated permissions to **write** into event log.

Creation of an event source is possible outside the app (e.g. from the installer). The topic is covered in the official documentation of [EventLogAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#trouble-EventLog)